# How to rotate coordinates based on the direction of motion?

Tags: geometry

### Objective

I want to auto-rotate a road network based on the direction of motion of a car.

### Background

I collect the live position data of a simulated car. Just like the google maps application, I want to rotate the road network to orient it based on the current direction of motion. All I have are the coordinates of the car position as well as the coordinates of the road network. The details of how I plot them in `R` are [here under the `Shiny app` section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518873/insert-and-play-audio-clips-based-on-a-condition-in-shiny-app).
Following is an example. The x, y coordinates change with time. But the road network is not oriented to the position of the car.

[image]

### Desired output

I want to change the coordinates so that the road network and car positions shows up as follows:

[image]

### How to transform the coordinates?

I want to know if this problem is solvable given the data. Based on the following figure, I am assuming that I need to calculate the new coordinates by making the angle theta 180 degrees (because I want everything to be parallel to y-axis). Is that correct? Please guide me how can I rotate this map? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the direction of travel to remain parallel to the $y$-axis of the output graph all the time? In other words, if the car you are tracking changes lanes, do you want the road network object in your output graph to rotate to allow the direction of travel to remain vertical?

Comment: @YNK yes, I want the direction of travel to remain vertical.

Comment: What is your assumption about origin?

Comment: @Moti (x=0,y=0)

Comment: In that case you just multiply by cos and sin to rotate the point by the angel you measure.

Comment: @Moti Could you please clarify?  Multiply what by cos and sin?

Comment: New x is always 0. New y is $x_2/ \sin(\theta)$